# Legder Nano S can't effective authorization

Tags: nearprotocol, ledger-nano-s

I use ledger nano S for https://wallet.betanet.near.org/, and the ledger nano S successful configuration. after I delete all key from my account and just keep 1 Full Access Key(create by ledger nano S).

Now I can't add other fullaccess key. Whatever method is used.when I did: near login --useLedgerKey. the web verify page will show:

An error occurred while approving this action. Please try again!

When I did add Seed Phrase enable, on the [Enter the following word from your recovery phrase to complete the setup process.] page, When I confirm it in the Ledger it will show:

> An error occurred while setting up seed phrase recovery. Please try again!

Actually , my ledger still will show confirm info:

> DANGER: This gives full access to a device other than Ledger

when I make a transaction  push √ button. it still show the error:

> An error occurred while approving this action. Please try again!

I think it's a bug, when use just keep 1 access key form ledger nano S.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qITBH.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU0Us.png)

my account : catcatcat.test

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're asking. Might you consider rephrasing?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an error on the NEAR Wallet side. If you don't mind me asking, what is your account ID? I can better understand what is happening by viewing the chain activity associated with this.

Comment: catcatcat.test.
For "an error on the NEAR Wallet side" I think so. because I use near cli
 by ledger nano is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it takes time to get new app version published in Ledger Live (even in Developer Mode). First version that got published (1.0.0) has the bug with adding full access keys.

As far as I know this bug is fixed in latest version available here:
https://github.com/LedgerHQ/app-near/pull/2

Best shot for now is to try compiling it from source following instructions in README:
https://github.com/LedgerHQ/app-near/blob/6a8d3263896fdf65ac06961c6e7ed6a9912d5480/README.md

Comment: @NIUNIU 932d214 isn't latest commit, it is still v1.0.0 so expected to have the same issue. Check https://github.com/LedgerHQ/app-near/commits/master – Ledger has merged latest changes. Ledger Live update coming soon.